# Excel VBA: Is it possible to Copy & Paste PICTURES between workbooks WITHOUT using Windows clipboard?

Tags: vba, image, copy, paste

I searched a lot in this forum (and other ones...) but I actually didn't find a solution:

*[Here the backgound of the problem]*
I'm writing an excel VBA program that will recursively open all excel files in a folder, retrieve a lot of data for those files and store such data in a Table (actually a DataBase) of the program file itself. The stored data will be then used for checks, elaborations and reporting.

Within the data to be collected and store I also need to take a couple of Picture from each analyzed file (the pictures are always on the same sheets and have always the same name). The picture will only be used in the final reports where they shall be pasted.

I'm trying to assign such pictures to Object type variables and the collect them in a array (I've in mind an array for Picture A, where each item of the array should contain the Picture A object  from the i-th analyzed file; a second similar array for Picture B)

*[The Problem]*
I can get the Pictures and assign them to the object variables, but I cannot collect such object in the arrays.
I guess this is not technically feasible...

The only solution I found is to copy & paste the pictures with something like:

```
    For Each pic In SourceWorkbook.Sheets("source").Pictures
        i = i + 1
        pic.Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("destination").Range("A" & i).PasteSpecial
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("dst").Pictures(pic.Name)
            .Name = "Pasted Picture #" & i
            .Visible = False
        End With
    Next
```

But I know this type of solution uses the WIndows clipboard that lead to at least 2 problems:

- it is quite (if not very) slow
- it requires to implement some delay after the Copy method (to wait and check that the picture has been actually copied in the clipboard) before using the Paste method, otherwise an error is likely to occur.

Does anyone has some suggestion to solve or optimize this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your title says different workbooks, but your code says same workbook, different worksheets. Which are you trying to do?

Comment: I am afraid, it is not possible... VBA does not offer too much from this point of view. Only VBA Corel (from what I know) has been adapted/designed to duplicate shapes without using clipboard. I mean, no any picture inserted on a sheet can be copied without using clipboard. But, if the pictures in discussion are placed on `Image` `activeX` controls (or `Image` from user form), they can be placed on other `Image` controls without using clipboard.

Comment: @braX: there is any difference? Anyway, what I actually need it to copy the pictures from one workbook (opened via VBA code) to another workbook (the file that hosts the VBA codes). I just edited the code above in accordance.

Comment: @FaneDuru: no, the picture are not in any activeX, they are quite similar to screenshots copied from screen and simply pasted in the excel file.

Comment: Well, there are not VBA methods able to copy shapes without using clipboard. Your problem is complex, as I could understand it.. You need to open the workbooks in order to "retrieve a lot of data" and also copying the pictures in discussion. If you would only need to extract some pictures, theoretically may exist a method to do it without opening the workbook, which will save some time for the used code. The basic idea is that the recent workbooks (`xlsx, xlsm, xlsa, xlsb`) are, in fact, **zip archives containing the images (you are interested to) in a "media" subfolder.

Comment: The names there are something like `Image1.jpg`, `Image2.bmp` and so on. The correlation between these generic names and sheets where they exists and their name there is done in more `xml` and `rels` files. The can be read and correlated. But programmatically renaming the workbook (as zip) and unzip it takes some time, according to the workbook size. It should be less than opening the workbook and part of correlation process should not take two much. But doing what you try, in two steps, will not lead in any gain I am afraid...

Answer (score 0):

Right now, The only solution I found is to copy using the clipboard. I used the code taken from another topic on stackoverflow:

```
    Option Explicit

'Does the clipboard contain a bitmap/metafile?
Public Declare PtrSafe Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Integer) As Long

'Open the clipboard to read
Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal Hwnd As LongPtr) As Long

'clear clipboard
Public Declare PtrSafe Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long

'Get a pointer to the bitmap/metafile
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As LongPtr 'wformat as long ?


'Close the clipboard
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long


'for waiting
Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Sub Clear_Clipboard()
OpenClipboard (0&)
EmptyClipboard
CloseClipboard
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub



Sub PastePic(ByVal Pic As Shape, ByRef WB As Workbook, ByVal Sh As String, ByVal Rg As String)
    Dim T#

    Clear_Clipboard

    Pic.Copy

    'wait until the clipboard gets a pic, but not over 3 seconds (avoid infinite loop)
    T = Timer
    Do
        Waiting (2)
    Loop Until Is_Pic_in_Clipboard Or Timer - T > 1

    WB.Sheets(Sh).Paste Destination:=WB.Sheets(Sh).Range(Rg) 'paste to a range without select
    
End Sub

Sub Waiting(ByVal Mili_Seconds&)
Sleep Mili_Seconds
End Sub

Function Is_Pic_in_Clipboard() As Boolean
If IsClipboardFormatAvailable(2) <> 0 Or IsClipboardFormatAvailable(14) <> 0 Then Is_Pic_in_Clipboard = True '2-14 =bitmap et Picture JPEG
End Function
```

But this code still give me problems sometimes:

> Error No. 1004 "Paste method of Worksheet class failed"

That I guess is due to the trial to paste the picture when it is not yet available in the clipboard...

**What to do? Just try to increase the time wasting until I get no more errors?**

Thanks!

Comment: You should add this information to your question not insert it as new answer if your problem isn't completely solved